Question about lattice with dense projection
Let $H\subset \operatorname{GL}(n,\mathbb{C})$ be a connected, semisimple algebraic group defined over $\mathbb{Q}$. Fix a number field $K$ with $[K:\mathbb{Q}]=3$ that is not totally real. Denote its ring of integers by $\mathcal{O}_{K}$. The Borel-Harish Chandra theorem says that $H(\mathcal{O}_{K})$ embeds as a lattice in $H(\mathbb{R})\times H(\mathbb{C})$. Is it true that the projection of $H(\mathcal{O}_{K})$ into the first factor $H(\mathbb{R})$ is dense?
Edit: I am asking because I am trying to understand the proof of Theorem 3 in "Dense subgroups with property (T) in Lie groups" by de Cornulier https://ems.press/journals/cmh/articles/1565. In the last paragraph of the first step, this Borel-Harish-Chandra construction shows up. It is somehow essential that the projection into $H(\mathbb{R})$ is dense, since the aim of the paper is to construct dense subgroups with property (T).
Also, I got quite confused reading about these things. Theorem 3.7 of http://constantinkogler.com/Files/Topics_on_Linear_Groups.pdf claims that the projections of $H(\mathcal{O}_{K})$ into both factors are dense. But if $H(\mathbb{R})$ is compact, then the projection of $H(\mathcal{O}_{K})$ in the second factor $H(\mathbb{C})$ should again be a lattice hence discrete. Am I missing something?

Yes, if $H(\mathbf{R})$ is compact then the projection is discrete (and hence not dense unless $H=1$). Indeed the theorem in the linked paper is not precise enough in the definition of "irreducible lattice" (it is even false or ambiguous in the case without compact factors, since $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{Z}[\sqrt{2}])^2$ is a non-irreducible lattice in $\mathrm{SL}_2(\mathbf{R})^4$ but all projections to simple factors are dense).

Keep in mind that these are notes written by a student.

@MoisheKohan as written, it's authored by a professor. It's unclear anyway from the formulation whether it's been checked by the professor.

@YCor: Yes, but written by a student. To which extent the student understood the material is also far from clear.

OK. I'm not sure we should argue much more about it, but it means it would be better to find a reference with a more precise result. Have you checked Dave Witte Morris' book?

@YCor Thanks, I will have a look at the book. Actually I am trying to understand an easy case of a paper. I updated my question accordingly.

In my paper I refer to Margulis' book. In Margulis' book (Prop 7 p136-137), Margulis justifies density by "the strong approximation theorem", II.6.8 of the same book (which he attributes to Platonov in his earlier 1980 3-page paper), and indeed the theorem in this II.6.8 (p.111) seems to do the job, but I haven't checked in detail. Anyway, it seems that he doesn't refer to Harish-Chandra (as I would have expected).

@YCor Thanks a lot!
